# awstats password protection

Tags: awstats

in awstat.domain.conf file  what should be the value of

AllowAccessFromWebToFollowingAuthenticatedUsers=

what should i put here

current value is empty and i am getting

```
Error: Access to statistics is only allowed from an authenticated session to authenticated users.

Setup ('/etc/awstats/awstats.domain.conf' file, web server or permissions) may be wrong.
Check config file, permissions and AWStats documentation (in 'docs' directory).
```

Comment: Have you followed what the message said and checked the AWStats documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AllowAccessFromWebToAuthenticatedUsersOnly=0


# This parameter give the list of all authorized authenticated users to view
# statistics for this domain/config file. This parameter is used only if
# AllowAccessFromWebToAuthenticatedUsersOnly is set to 1.
# Change : Effective immediatly
# Example: "user1 user2"
# Example: "__REMOTE_USER__"
# Default: ""
#
AllowAccessFromWebToFollowingAuthenticatedUsers=""
# When this parameter is define to something, the IP address of the user that
# read its statistics from a browser (when AWStats is used as a CGI) is
# checked and must match one of the IP address values or ranges.
# Change : Effective immediatly
# Example: "127.0.0.1 123.123.123.1-123.123.123.255"
# Default: ""
#
AllowAccessFromWebToFollowingIPAddresses=""
```

Comment: @lain:  I'm not sure what you edited but I pulled my post straight from a working awstats installation.